Can I use AddressSanitizer in C++Builder CLANG compiler?
I found that AddressSanitizer exists in the Clang compiler. And C++Builder uses the clang compiler. Can I mix these two things together? It doesn't work for me.
I tried to put the -fsanitize=address compiler flag into a simple 64bit Windows project in C++Builder 10.2. I got compiler error:

Error: Unresolved external '__asan_report_store8' referenced from …

Can this option work in C++Builder clang? Or is C++Builder Clang just based on the original Clang and this function is missing?

In C++Builder 10.2, the Win64 compiler uses clang 3.3, and the clang 3.3 AddressSanitizer doc says: "The AddressSanitizer run-time library should be linked to the final executable, so make sure to use clang (not ld) for the final link step. When linking shared libraries, the AddressSanitizer run-time is not linked, so -Wl,-z,defs may cause link errors". I'm not sure if C++Bulider uses clang for linking. Since you added the flag manually, you may need to link to the AddressSanitizer runtime manually as well.
